# ¿Cómo paso el valor de una String ya almacenado de un método a otro?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Duda{
  public static void main (String[] args){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Sytem.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática:");
  String nota = sc.nextLine()
  }

static void pass(){
  system.out.println("La nota del estudiante es" + nota);
  int i = 5;
  }
 }
```

> Se que se puede poner todo el código en el método main sin complicarme la vida, solo hago está pregunta para aprender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que:

1. Agregar el parámetro que recibirá el método. Teniendo en cuenta que los tipos deben coincidir. Si aquí `nota` es del tipo `String`, en el método debe ser del mismo tipo
2. Invocar el método pasándole el parámetro

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Duda{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Sytem.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática:");
        String nota = sc.nextLine()

        /*Aquí invocamos el método y le pasamos el parámetro*/
        pass(nota);
    }

    /*El método es modificado, se habilita para recibir nota en parámetro*/
    static void pass(String nota){
        System.out.println("La nota del estudiante es" + nota);
        /* No sé para que es i ... Si no lo vas a usar no lo declares ahí*/
        int i = 5;
    }
 }
```

Un método puede recibir varios parámetros y de varios tipos, separados por coma. Puede recibir variables primarias, o puede recibir objetos completos: Clases, Listas, etc, etc. O sea, todo lo que necesite para hacer su trabajo.

Para más detalles consulta la documentación: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, se me olvido agregar esto

Comment: @Dr.Boom ¿agregar qué?  Este sitio es de preguntas / respuestas. Uno pregunta y otros responden (a veces uno mismo puede responder, pero no es el caso aquí). No entiendo por qué agregaste una respuesta con mi respuesta ¿?

Comment: Perdón soy nuevo en esto, apenas tengo 13 años, pero bueno mi objetivo no era responder si no agregar un complemento para formularte otra pregunta ¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable del método pass al método main?
Disculpa, enserio lo siento

Comment: No hay ningún problema @Dr.Boom. Sólo tienes que borrar el código de abajo y listo. En cuanto a tu otra duda, debo decirte que este sitio funciona por preguntas. Si surgen nuevas dudas debes abrir otra pregunta con ella. ¿Por qué? Porque cada pregunta sirve no sólo al que la plantea, sino a otros futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. O sea, este sitio no es como un foro de discusión.

Comment: Y si me puedes responder la pregunta que te dije hace un momento? de como pasar una variable del método pass al método main.

Comment: @Dr.Boom pasar una variable del método `pass` al método `main`  no tiene ningún sentido. El método `Main` es el punto de entrada de tu aplicación, o sea, el método que se ejecuta siempre cuando la aplicación se abre.

Comment: Pero se puede?.

Comment: @Dr.Boom llamar al método `main` desde  `pass` que es llamado desde `main`  no se puede... crearías un bucle infinito. A no ser que manejes en las llamadas un contador o algo que llegado a un punto provoque una salida del programa o pase a otra cosa. Si preguntas sólo por curiosidad, me parece algo interesante para tratarlo en una pregunta aparte y tener la posible respuesta de varios de los usuarios del sitio. En cualquier caso, puedes hacer pruebas tú mismo. Pero si pasas sin más de `main` a `pass` y de `pass`  a `main` .. estamos hablando de un bucle infinito, espero que tu PC no explote :)

Comment: @Dr.Boom por ejemplo así se puede: `private static int counter=0;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        while (counter<5){
           pass();
        }
    }
    
    public static void pass(){
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Estoy en pass");
        String [] args = new String[2];
            args[0] = "arg 1";
            args[1] = "arg 2";
        main(args);
    }` porque hay un punto de salida, pero si quitas el `while` te imprime todas las veces que puede `Estoy en pass`, hasta que da error: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` ...

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta acerca de como pasar una variable del metodo pass al main, la respuesta es que debes cambiar la forma en la que declaras el metodo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Duda{
   public static void main (String[] args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   Sytem.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática:");
   String nota = sc.nextLine()
   System.out.println("La nota modificada es: "+pass(nota));//Aca usas el metodo como 
                                               //si estuvieras usando una variable
   }

static int pass(String nota){ //Se deja de usar la palabra void y se ultiliza en su lugar el tipo 
                                //de variable u objeto que el metodo devuelve

   int notaAumentada=5+parseInt(nota);

   return nota;
   }
}
```

Espero que te haya servido, te felicito por estar adentrandote en la programacion siendo tan joven, segui para adelante y no te frustres, que es dificil pero satisfactorio. Un saludo